# How to Make Link File in Command Prompt Windows?

Tags: linker

I want to make link File which in that link file there are more file. Example, I want to combine several library files into one to make it easier to compile. If on Linux, i use the command :

ar -c

How about in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft tool for managing static libraries is a called `lib`. It will
be provided with MS Visual C++ or a developer SDK. To build a static library `mylibrary.lib`
with it, run:

```
>lib mylibary.lib file0.obj file1.obj ... filen.obj
```

at the Developer command propmpt.

[Here is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t.aspx)

The file format of `lib` archives is the same as that of Unix `ar` archives.